# Get DOM element that has been created within a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a node application and I have a pug template that are coded up, the pug template represents one project, and within that are shown related targets (so a one to many relationship - one project can have many targets).

What I want to do, is have a user be able to click on the DOM element representing a target, and it open up a modal form or something similar, and allow it to be edited. I'm not sure of the best way to do this. So this is my pug template element for each:

```
each target in project.targets
           .target__card
              .target__avatar
                 h6.target__title= target.title
                 input#targetId(type='hidden' value=`${target._id}`)
```

So I've got my hidden id in there and it's all peachy. I want to be able to click on it and it open a form that can edit it and then submit to my endpoint. But if I have a javascript function like this:

```
const targetCard = document.querySelector('.target__card')

if (targetCard) {
          targetCard.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
             const target = document.getElementById('targetId').value
             console.log('target is ', target)
  })
}
```

then this is only going to work for the first DOM element. But do I really need to loop through again, in my javascript, or something like that? I'm already looping in the template, and the information is ' just sitting there' already, I can see it. It seems wasteful to loop through it again in a js function, even if I did know the best way to do that (which I'm not sure I do). Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Can I embed a form in each element that can simply be hidden and unhidden? That seems a bit wasteful too.